# Can't iterate through some numbers even when they look like a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to parse list of part numbers from a webpage available within a script tag. I've scooped out the relevant portion to create this demo as the site requires authentication.

When I try the regex below, I can fetch the numbers but the problem is I can't iterate through the numbers while printing even when the numbers appears to be within a list.

I've tried with:

```
import re

elems = """
<script type="text/javascript">
    $SPC.PartNos = [1922624,1922625,1922626,1922627,1922628,1922629,1922630];
    $SPC.QuantityUnits = ['PC','PC','PC','PC','PC','PC','PC'];
</script>
"""

items = re.findall(r"SPC\.PartNos[^[]+(.*?);",elems)[0]
# print(items)
for item in items:
    print(item)
```

Current output (truncated):

```
[
1
9
2
2
6
2
4
,
1
9
2
```

Expected output:

```
1922624
1922625
1922626
1922627
1922628
1922629
1922630
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of the pattern `[^[]+` will match any char except `[` and then `(.*?)` will include the brackets.

Then you are looping the string returned by group 1, which will give you the single characters including the `[` and `]`

You could get the group 1 value without the brackets, and then loop on splitting by a comma.

```
import re

pattern = r"SPC\.PartNos = \[([^][]*)]"
elems = """
<script type="text/javascript">
    $SPC.PartNos = [1922624,1922625,1922626,1922627,1922628,1922629,1922630];
    $SPC.QuantityUnits = ['PC','PC','PC','PC','PC','PC','PC'];
</script>
"""

m = re.search(pattern, elems)
if m:
    for item in m.group(1).split(','):
        print(item)
```

Output

```
1922624
1922625
1922626
1922627
1922628
1922629
1922630
```

Comment: While your answer solves the issue of iteration, could you suggest any way to make single characters to a list so that I can iterate them through as I wished to achieve in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: @SMTH You can iterate again through all the matches to see the separate characters like  https://ideone.com/vWlZej Or you can iterate through the group 1 value to get each single char. If the char is not a comma, concat it to a string. When you encounter the comma, add the string to a list. See https://ideone.com/DVKGQ2